# To get the only related original data in the former dataset,not dataset after standardization , by the reduced principal components that I calculated

Tags: matlab, pca

I am doing Master Thesis with the title of 'Efficient automated Lung noudules Detection System'.Now,I calculate principal components by using Matlab functions.In this case,I face the difficulty that I don't know how can I get **the only related original data in the former dataset** by using **the reduced principal components** ,not data after standardization. Could you please help me , seniors?

The code that I calculated like this:

The dataset:

```
Contrast    Correlation    Energy     Homogenity
13.316      0.94208        0.99623    0.99979   
15.319       0.9335        0.99619    0.99976   
11.836      0.94852        0.99625    0.99982   
18.778      0.91848        0.99614    0.99971   
26.684      0.88416        0.99602    0.99959   
30.757        0.867        0.99594    0.99953   
23.719      0.89703        0.99606    0.99963   
37.703      0.83697        0.99583    0.99942   

B = zscore(Array2);%Normalize the dataset
disp(B);

[coeff,score,latent] =pca(B);

-0.5000    0.2391    0.4391    0.7071
0.5000   -0.3818    0.7773   -0.0000
0.4999    0.8602    0.1009   -0.0000
0.5000   -0.2391   -0.4391    0.7071

1.9689    0.0084    0.0014    0.0000
1.5122   -0.0231   -0.0011    0.0000
2.2903    0.0010    0.0017   -0.0000
0.7612   -0.0060   -0.0011    0.0000
-0.9552    0.0331   -0.0012   -0.0000
-1.8799   -0.0326   -0.0004   -0.0000
-0.3116    0.0184   -0.0012    0.0000
-3.3860    0.0009    0.0019    0.0000

3.9995
0.0004
0.0000
0.0000
```

And I calculated reduced PC:

```
PCReduced=score(1,:);%get the best principal components of the first   columns
disp(PCReduced);

1.9689
1.5122
2.2903
0.7612
-0.9552
-1.8799
-0.3116
-3.3860
```

Now, I need to get the related original data in the former dataset to use as input feature vectors in ANFIS. Please help me how to calculate to get the best feature observations?

Comment: This seems a bit too technical to go on stackoverflow. Maybe try a forum related to your line of research?

Comment: Maybe it needs a couple more tags, but I don't think anything's  too technical for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just use crosscovariance `xcov()` between each of your original variables and your selected projection.

The variables with higher crosscovariance are the ones that contribute the most to your chosen projection.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115130 for a stats reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer,sir.Could you please check my calculation kindly?The priginal dataset is Array2,standardize dataset is B,so i calculated crosscovariance matrix as  Org=(B'*score)/7;
 disp(Org); where, no: of observations is 8.
   -1.9999    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000
    1.9998   -0.0002    0.0000   -0.0000
    1.9996    0.0004    0.0000   -0.0000
    1.9999   -0.0001   -0.0000    0.0000        ,now Can I use the first column as feature vectors for the next analysis directly,sir?Thank you for your benevolence :-) @xvan

Comment: Org=(B'*score)/7;
 disp(Org);
   -1.9999    0.0001    0.0000    0.0000
    1.9998   -0.0002    0.0000   -0.0000
    1.9996    0.0004    0.0000   -0.0000
    1.9999   -0.0001   -0.0000    0.0000

Comment: I didnt undertand your numbers.

Comment: I made one mistake, you should use cross correlation instead of covariance between your chosen PC projection (one in your case), so the results are normalised and can be compared.

Comment: For ANFIS, as you propose, it's better to work with the data projected to the PC space, than reduce the dimension on the  original dataset. How many PC dimensions you need depends on what you're working on.